# How to make a video call like we have in viber/skype

Tags: android

I am developing an application where i have webservices, now i want to make a video call from one user to another like we have in VIBER or other Chat application.

Comment: Check WebRTC for android.

Comment: @Raghunandan My client told me that he will give me web login system, my work is just to develop an application like viber, so can i use this WebRTC in this type of application, i am just bit new in chat app development, please help me ...

Comment: check the docs page. I also haven't implemented. But most of them use webrtc.

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you, please tell me when you got some useful link about that.or got some idea